# Am I using ispell or aspell, and where is the local dictionary saved?

Tags: emacs, dictionary, ispell

When spell checking in Emacs, I am accustomed to using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ispell` to invoke the spell checker.  I have read that some people have their Emacs configured so this invokes aspell rather than ispell (or hunspell, possibly).

How can I tell whether I'm invoking ispell or aspell?

I looked in my `.emacs` file (in my home directory) and don't see anything referencing either.

Also, (assuming I am using ispell), where is the "private dictionary" saved where I insert words into.  I'd like to back up that file (and/or transfer it to another machine).

Comment: @lawlist - the thread link you posted in your comment answered it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `ispell-program-name` tells you what is being used.

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`ispell-program-name`

*ispell.el* states:

```
(defconst ispell-pdict-keyword "Local IspellPersDict: "
  "The keyword for defining buffer local dictionaries.
Keyword must be followed by the filename of a personal dictionary.
The last occurring definition in the buffer will be used.")
....
;; Change IspellPersDict to IspellPersDict: to enable the following line.
;; Local IspellPersDict ~/.ispell_lisp
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the ispell-program-name function. Using Emacs 23.3.

Comment: ispell package might not be loaded the first time... at least this is what it seemed like as first time i tried to look up that variable, nothing showed up.  Opened that ispell.el.gz, found `ispell-program-name`, hit `C-h v` and searched for that variable and it showed up this time around.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to use the function `ispell-check-version`